# Does AVDepthData capture depth data from the selfie camera on iPhone X?

Tags: ios, iphone-x, truedepth-camera

I'm trying to figure out how to get detailed depth data (the raw data) from the front-facing camera on the iPhone X. Apple's docs suggest that [AVDepthData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avdepthdata) will return this data, but I've not be able to confirm this.

Is this the correct property to use to access that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The WWDC 2017 session "Capturing Depth in iPhone Photography" (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/507/) covers this for the dual-camera set up on the back, and it uses AVDepthData to return depth information. The TrueDepth camera uses the same protocol.

Comment: Yes, I was able to get this up and running by modifying the AVCam sample code. Thanks!

Comment: ...and for others coming to this answer, *how* do you modify the sample code? (The key part is selecting the `builtInTrueDepthCamera` capture device.)

Comment: In the sample code, the key point is to adjust AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession to include .builtInTrueDepthCamera. From there, implement:
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?). 

You're then able to extract the depth data from the photo object return in the delegate callback: 
    let depthData = photo.depthData